# Creating .flv files on the iphone without using ffmpeg

Tags: iphone, flash, ios, ffmpeg, flv

How does one create **.flv** files on the iPhone?

I am aware of ffmpeg (with its **LGPL** restrictions).  But are there other APIs that have been ported to `iOS`?

Comment: I reverted to the original question because even if the question is no longer relevant to you it may still be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a strange question. .Flvs don't 'live' in the iPhone universe. They're not supported under iOS.